# C++ equivalent of java StringBuilder.replace

Tags: java, c++, stringbuilder

What is the C++ equivalent of the following java function?

```
public StringBuilder replace(int start,
                int end,
                String str)
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace(int,%20int,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the replace all function we are using,

```
string ReplaceAll(string original, string replaceThis, string replaceWith)
{
    std::string::size_type pos = 0;
    while((pos = original.find(replaceThis, pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
      original.replace(pos, (replaceThis.length()), replaceWith);
      pos += replaceWith.length();
    }
    return original;
}
```

You can also refer the following link for better understanding.

[REPLACE IN C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/)

Answer (score 0):

C++'s [string::replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/) is pretty similar to what you're looking for. However, instead of finding the range you want to replace with the left and right integer indexes, you pass in [string iterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/begin/).

Comment: `std::string::replace` can be called with either indexes or iterators.